# Center alignment print format specifier implementation detail

Tags: python

In Python (2.7 and above, probably other versions too), it is possible to create a string that is centered by doing something like this:

```
'{:^10}'.format('abc')
```

The meaning of 'centered' is pretty clear when the total number of padding characters is even, but what about when it is odd?

When I print the above in vanilla C Python (and IPython), I get

```
'   abc    '
```

This appears to put the extra pad character on the right. However, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) do not explicitly mention a spec for this behavior. Is the behavior of the centering format specifier in the presence of an odd number of padding characters specified somewhere, or is it an implementation detail that is not to be relied on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to rely on this.  I don't know that it is documented anywhere, but the [standard python test suite](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/test/test_unicode.py#l1060) asserts that the extra space is added on the right.  Since `test` is part of the standard library, it's a good starting point for other python implementations and they'll be aiming for compliance with the reference implementation wherever possible.

Comment: What about variable width characters like in Helvetica?

Comment: @Marichyasana -- I'm not sure that I understand the question ... Python is working with bytestrings and unicode strings.  Those don't know anything about what font will be used to render the strings so I suppose you could argue that this _won't_ center the way you want with those strings.  It also won't center the way you want if you render the string in HTML because the HTML will collapse the whitespace.  In those cases, presumably you need to do something to the renderer to tell it how you want the string to be centered (which it outside of python's jurisdiction)

Comment: @mgilson. Thanks. My PR to Pyformat.io has been accepted: https://github.com/ulope/pyformat.info/pull/38, probably on the basis of your answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist -- Happy to help.